# How to add a background image that moves independent to main layer in Cocos and box2d

Tags: xcode, background, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, layer

I want to add a background to a side scroll game that moves at a different rate to the main game layer. What would be the best way to do this? I may want 2 background layers, each scrolling slower than the other to give a sense of depth when the player moves.

Also, what is the best way to create a layer, and have direct control over it? At the moment a   layer is created but I cant access it in other parts of the code. This is how its done by default which is the way I am using:

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCParallaxNode is good for you.

```
    // background layer: another image
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
    background.scale = 1.5f;
    background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);


    // create a void node, a parent node
    CCParallaxNode *voidNode = [CCParallaxNode node];

    [voidNode addChild:background z:-1 parallaxRatio:ccp(0.4f,0.5f) positionOffset:CGPointZero];

    [voidNode addChild:tilemap z:1 parallaxRatio:ccp(2.2f,1.0f) positionOffset:ccp(0,-200)];

    [voidNode addChild:cocosImage z:2 parallaxRatio:ccp(3.0f,2.5f) positionOffset:ccp(200,800)];


    [self addChild:voidNode];
```

Refer ParallaxTest in Cocos2D sample.

Comment: Thanks Raj. Any suggestions how to access a certain layer?

Comment: see my answer in this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754390/cocos2d-get-layers-position-in-scene-from-another-class/12787634#12787634